# Is it okay to delete Contents of botocore/data/* to Keep within AWS Lambda Limits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, botocore

I wanted to upload .zip file to AWS Lambda. The limits are 250 MB unzipped. botocore is one of the requirements. Is it ok to delete botocore/data/* in order to fit the limits? Is this data used by the library?

Comment: It really depends on how you use the libraries in your code.

Comment: Do you actually need to include the boto3/botocore libraries in your upload? They're already present (at specific supported versions) in the Python Lambda runtime environment.